# Angular Only adding Comma 6 digit number

Tags: c#, .net, angular, typescript

In my Angular project when I have a four digit number there is no comma but when I have a 6 digit number the comma will display. Can this be something with the locate code? Any Help would be great

```
    <span class="compiled-sentence-on-panel-header" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
        <span *ngIf="!hasCompiledText()">New entry</span>
        <span *ngIf="hasCompiledText()"><strong>{{getAgentNameLabel()}}</strong>&nbsp;<span innerHtml="{{entry.CompiledText}}"></span><template [ngIf]="getRelationshipString().length > 0">&nbsp;<span>{{getRelationshipString()}}</span></template></span>
    </span>
```

Comment: which one you are binding? post the component.ts code too

Comment: @Sajeetharan, getRelationshipString() is the one I am binding? How would I find the component.ts file?

Comment: did you check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have , at every thousand , you can use a separator using [**`Decimal`**](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) pipe as  follows,

```
{{ getRelationshipString() | number:'.2'}}
```

**[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-number-format-pipe-fbsfuu?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

if you do nto want **`,`** at all, then you need to implement your own **`custom pipe`**.

Comment: Still getting the same result is there anything I am missing.    `<span class="compiled-sentence-on-panel-header" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
            <span *ngIf="!hasCompiledText()">New entry</span>
            <span *ngIf="hasCompiledText()"><strong>{{getAgentNameLabel()}}</strong>&nbsp;<span innerHtml="{{entry.CompiledText}}"></span><template [ngIf]="getRelationshipString().length > 0">&nbsp;<span>{{getRelationshipString() | number:'.2'} }}</span></template></span>
        </span>`

Comment: can you produce a stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-number-format-pipe-fbsfuu?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Should I be able to add my localhost address into the window?

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: Sorry - In the Navigation panel should I be able to enter the local host address? Like http://localhost:50159/#/ 
This sandbox is configured to only navigate webpages whose origin is